# Parsing JSON feed to PHP and then manipluating data?

Tags: php, parsing, json

I have a JSON feed which is private (by IP address) and I can parse it using the command

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://#");
```

This is what the feed looks like and the command works - it dumps the data properly when using json_decode($json); or  json_decode($json,true); and i do a var dump.

```
    {
    "Holder": [
        {
            "name": "Subholder One",
            "operators": [
        {
          "username": "User1",
          "status": 3
        },
        {
          "username": "User2",
          "status": 3
        },
        {
          "username": "User3",
          "status": 3
        },
        {
          "username": "User4",
          "status": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Subholder Two",
      "operators": [
        {
          "username": "User5",
          "status": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Subholder Three",
      "operators": [
        {
          "username": "User6",
          "status": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Subholder Four",
      "operators": [
        {
          "username": "User7",
          "status": 1
        },
        {
          "username": "User8",
          "status": 3
        },
        {
          "username": "User9",
          "status": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I use the simple, following code with a line of data, with **no** file_get_contents but a line of data it works:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->username;
echo $obj->status;
```

When I use file_get_contents it doesn't work.

**All I want to be able to do is display Username and Status (number converted to a phrase which I've done) for all the data and singularly by username.**

For example on a profile page for User 1, I want to parse their "username" and "status", convert the status number to a corresponding phrase and display on screen.

I am scratching my head here...so any help gratefully received.

Comment: You haven't got valid JSON data.

Comment: Paste the file_get_contents result here. Maybe this funtion is not allowed to get contents via http? (php.ini)

Comment: can you paste what you get into file_get_contents as result before json_decode ? because your pasted json code in above question is valid

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  $obj = json_decode($json, true);

  echo $obj['username'];
  echo $obj['status'];
```

Comment: Thanks tried that already - doesn't work :o(  When I manually code the data it works, pulling from the feed it doesn't.

Comment: Hi all - anyone help?  When calling in from a feed it still doesn't work :(

Comment: PHP `echo` doesn't work, but `print_r` does...the problem being I wish to be able to go if username = User1, then status= 3 individually...i.e. use the relevant User Info and Status on a suite of separate pages...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$request_url ="http://mysamplefeed.com/";
$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);
$my_response = json_decode($requests);
foreach($my_response->Holder as $item){
'<p>' .$item->username; . '</p>'
'<p>' .$item->status; . '</p>'
}
```